# Como posicionar la vista de un treeview en la ultima fila insertada?

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en Python y estoy desarrollando un proyecto que incluye widgets treeview, estoy intentando hacer que al insertar una nueva fila se genere un scroll "automatico" y se posicione en la ultima fila insertada sin necesidad de hacerlo con un scroll_bar.

Probe dando un "tabla.focus(END)", pero al parecer no funciona asi.

Nota: La tabla en la BD tiene 100 registros, por lo cual es necesario ir desplazando cada que se inserta uno mas para verificar que se inserto bien, pero es un poco tedioso hacerlo manualmente.

**Tienen alguna idea de como podria hacerlo??**

De antemano muchas gracias por el apoyo.

```
#Creacion del Treeview:
tabla=ttk.Treeview(window, columns=("#1"), height=24)
    tabla.grid(row=1,column=1)
    tabla.heading("#0",text="Sample",anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.column("#0",minwidth=50, width=50, stretch=False)
    tabla.heading("#1",text="Pull Small",anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.column("#1",minwidth=70, width=70, stretch=False)

#Funcion para llenar el treeview con informacion de la Base de Datos:
def mostrarDatos():
        registros=tabla.get_children()
        for registro in registros:
            tabla.delete(registro)

        conn=sqlite3.connect("bdTensiones.db")
        cursor=conn.cursor()
        instruccion=f" SELECT sample, pull_1 FROM peelminsmall WHERE altura ='min' "
        cursor.execute(instruccion)

        for (sample,peel_small) in cursor:
                tabla.insert('',END,text=sample,values=peel_small)
        tabla.focus(END)
```

Comment: Estaba por darte una respuesta, pero luego pensé "los registros se mostrarían muy rapido, no le daría tiempo al usuario para revisar que se haya insertado bien". Te doy la respuesta de igual modo? Hay algo que entendí mal?

Comment: Claro que si Dante, cualquier aporte me puede ayudar mucho a encontrar una solucion, en si seria que al final de que traiga todos los datos se recorra el scroll hasta la ultima fila.

Comment: Perdona las preguntas, pero sería que apenas se carguen los datos vaya directamente hacia el final? O que vaya mostrando uno a uno y que cada cierto tiempo baje el scroll al siguiente item?

Comment: se obtienen los datos de un equipo PullTester mediante comunicacion Serial y se van guardando en la base de datos y a su vez se imprimen en el treeview, entonces segun va creciendo el numero de filas dejan de verse por lo cual hay que desplazar manualmente, y debido a que son 100 registros es muy tedioso tener que desplazar 75 veces hacia abajo del treeview(ya que los primeros 25 registros si se pueden ver sin necesidad de desplazar), espero haberme explicado un poco

Answer (score -1):

```
        # Posiciona la última línea de la ventana treeview
        tabla.yview((tabla.index(tabla.get_children()[-1])))
```

Comment: Recuerda poner el comentario en español :) Lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para explicar tu respuesta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.